# Keras custom loss function with dictionary at compiling

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, loss

I have a custom loss function and due to the reason I have multiple outputs I using a dictionary scheme to set loss functions:

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, 
        loss={
            'speed_output': 'mse', 
            'head_dir_output': 'mse',
            'position_output': 'mse'
            },
        loss_weights={
            'speed_output': 4., 
            'head_dir_output': 4.,
            'position_output': 4.
            },
        metrics={
            'speed_output': 'mse',
            'head_dir_output': 'mae',
            'position_output': 'accuracy'                            
    }
        )
```

**How can I use the same compile format but also implement my custom loss function?
I couldn't find the answer, so I would be grateful for each help.**

Comment: In the same way by a key_value pair dictionary and for the custom loss function the value would be set to the function without parenthesis instead of string value. in this way: `loss = {'output_layer_name': custom_loss_function}`

Comment: Thank you @SoroushMirzaei! As you said it worked